# Need to add several fragments in my adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to add more `Fragment` page in my adapt but I do not know how to do.
here is my code adpater with a single `Fragment` that works without problem.
thank you in advance for your help

```
class TabAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int) = SampleFragment() //SampleFragment() is my fragment

    override fun getCount() = 4

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int) = when (position) {
        0 -> "Music"
        1 -> "Market"
        2 -> "Films"
        else -> "Books"
    }
}
```

**And this is the code for my `SampleFragment()`**

```
class SampleFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false)
    }

}
```

Please help me to add each different `Fragment` for each Pagetitle in `Adapter`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to quickly add fragments into your adapter.

You require a ViewPager to hold all fragments you want to display.

Firstly edit your xml as follows.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Next Create new fragment and name it `Fragment_one.java`. Inside here you can do whatever you want like an activity. Create `Fragment_two.java` or as many as you want and instantiate it in your adapter.

Next create `fragmentAdapter.Java` and add these code (This is for your custom adapter)

```
public class fragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public fragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs){
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // Add as many fragment in this method
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Fragment_one frag_one = new Fragment_one ();
                return frag_one;
            case 1:
                Fragment_two frag_two = new Fragment_two ();
                return frag_two;
            default:
                return null;
         }

     }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
         return mNumOfTabs;
     }

}
```

Next add this inside `onCreate()` method in your `MainActivity.java`

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

//add as many fragments you want to add the "fragment 1" & "fragment 2" is 
//the title for your fragments, it starts for '0','1','2'...
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("fragment 1"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("fragment 2"));
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
final fragmentAdapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(),tablayout.geTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```